# Operating external file

Tags: python, operating-system, os.system

I see that the following command makes my program open an external file

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("filename")
```

I want my program to open the same file three times, so I wrote the line `os.system("filename")` three times in a row. Surprisingly, I see that when I run my program, the external file I want to operate is opened only once.

What can I do so the external file will be opened three time?

Comment: hey dude, did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with a number of cases and it works well in general if you repeat the `os.system(command)` line. You can try it yourself e.g. by test `os.system("echo 1")`.

**The only instance** I found not working is when you try to "open" a file with **Gedit on Linux**. In this case `os.system("gedit foo.py)` repeated multiple times opens foo only once. That's likely because you can get only one instance of gedit. See [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gedit-list/2008-December/msg00043.html).

**Workaround:** replace gedit with another editor such as kate, nano etc.